# How to find what tablespace a table/index is in on PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, tablespaces

How do I find out what tablespace a table (or index) is in with PostgreSQL (9.3)?

Comment: [pg_tables](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/view-pg-tables.html), [pg_indexes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/view-pg-indexes.html)

Comment: \l+ \d+ works ..

Answer (score 13):

For example, you have a table `example_table` (optionally in more than one schema):

```
SELECT tablespace 
FROM pg_tables 
WHERE tablename = 'example_table' [AND schemaname = 'your_schema'];
```

The same thing for the index `example_index`:

```
SELECT tablespace 
FROM pg_indexes 
WHERE indexname = 'example_index' [AND schemaname = 'your_schema'];
```